# A function that joins two arrays JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to write a function combineArray(arr1, arr2), which takes 2 arrays, and returns a new array consisting only of numeric elements of arrays arr1 and arr2.
For example:

```
 combineArray([12, "User01", 22, true, -8], ["Index", 6, null, 15]));  result --> [12, 22, -8, 6, 15]
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
function combineArray(arr1, arr2) {
    let numArr = [];
    let newArr = arr1.concat(arr2);
    for(let i = 0; i < newArr.lenght; i++){
        if(typeof newArr[i] == "number") numArr.push(newArr[i]);
    }
    return numArr
}

let result = combineArray([12, "User01", 22, true, -8], ["Index", 6, null, 15])
console.log(result)
```

But my function returns empty array.

Comment: `newArr.length` not `newArr.lenght`

Comment: Typo: `newArr.lenght` => `newArr.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
function returnNums(arr1, arr2) {
  let numArr = []
  for (const val of arr1) {
    if (typeof val === 'number') numArr.push(val)
  }
  for (const val of arr2) {
    if (typeof val === 'number') numArr.push(val)
  }
  return numArr;
}

console.log(returnNums([1, 2, 'a'], [3, 4, 'b']))
```

Also, the reason your code didn't work is because there is a typo. It's `length`, not `lenght`.

Comment: I just know how to do it in python, but in js I haven't yet fully mastered syntax

Comment: Yeah - you could use ```arr.filter()``` but I'm currently having my head split open by it, which is why I didn't link it.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to @Luke answer about typo in `length` property, you can save a lot of code by spread operator and `filter`.

```js
const combineArray = (arr1, arr2) => [...arr1, ...arr2].filter(i => typeof i === 'number');

let result = combineArray([12, "User01", 22, true, -8], ["Index", 6, null, 15])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Or `const combineArray = (...args) => args.flat().filter((i) => typeof i === 'number')`.

Comment: @BenAston, Yes that's good too.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
const a = [12, 'User01', 22, true, -8]
const b = ['Index', 6, null, 15]

// Merge arrays by [...a, ...b] then filter it
const result = [...a, ...b].filter(v => typeof v === 'number')
// Or using concat
const result = a.concat(b).filter(v => typeof v === 'number')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can generalize you combine function in this way

```js
const combine =  type => (...arrays) => arrays.flat().filter(v => typeof v === type )

const combineNumers = combine('number')
const combineStrings = combine('string')

let resultNumber = combineNumers([12, "User01", 22, true, -8], ["Index", 6, null, 15])
console.log(resultNumber)

let resultString = combineStrings([12, "User01", 22, true, -8], ["Index", 6, null, 15])
console.log(resultString)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your have made spelling mistake on length

```
for(let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
```